# How to connect to Webservice through Windows-mobile using Param?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How to connect to Webservice through Windows-mobile using Param ?

(ini or txt file)

thank's

Answer (score 0):

The WinINET API is the same on Windows CE as it is on Windows Desktop.  It allows you to easily talk to web sites (SSL too).  I do everything from C/C++, so I'm not sure how it differs for C#, but here is the basic info from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331(VS.85).aspx